# Airflow: how to get pip packages installed via their docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, pip, airflow

How can I install additional pip packages via the docker-compose file of [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.1/docker-compose.yaml)?

I am assuming that there should be a standard functionality to pick up a `requirements.txt` or something. When inspecting their [repo](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/IMAGES.rst#airflow-docker-images), I do see some ENV variables like `ADDITIONAL_PYTHON_DEPS` that hint me that this should be possible, but setting these in the docker-compose file doesn't actually install the libraries.

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.0.1}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG: 'true'
    ADDITIONAL_PYTHON_DEPS: python-bitvavo-api

volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a pretty detailed guide on how to achieve what you are looking for on the Airflow docs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#building-the-image). Depending on your requirements, this may be as easy as extending the original image using a  `From` directive while creating a new Dockerfile, or you may need to customize the image to suit your needs.

If you go with the **[Extending the image](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#extending-the-image)** approach your new Dockerfile will be something like this:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.0.1
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential my-awesome-apt-dependency-to-add \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user my-awesome-pip-dependency-to-add
```

Then you could just add something like these to the docker-compose file:

```yaml
...
version: "3"
x-airflow-common: &airflow-common
  build: . # this is optional
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-the_name_of_your_extended_image
  ...
...
```

Finally, build your image and turn everything back on using compose. Try the docs for details or a full explanation. Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 10):

Extending the image could be one way. Another way is adding the package in the docker compose.

For example, you want to pip apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs.
Then you go to docker compose file,

```
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: airflow_melodie1:test
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
   ......
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs other_packages}
```