# Adding Python Libraries to Airflow-Puckel on Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am new to Docker and Airflow and am having trouble figuring out the correct place to add the httplib2 Python library to the container. I am using the Airflow-Puckel image. Do I need to add it to the Dockerfile or the docker-compose yml file or both and once added do I just need to rebuild the container with up and it will run?

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience while learning *Airflow* and *Docker*, I strongly recommend using the [official docker-compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) file, maintained by Airflow. If you are on your first steps with Docker and Airflow, the guides and [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) may come in very handy and comprehensive.  Also, there is the fact that the images are more likely to be updated with the last Airflow version.

For example, once you are done with the initialization, you can take a look at this [article](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/production-deployment.html#customizing-or-extending-the-production-image) where it's is explained how to add packages to each of the services being run on Compose or how to set it up as production-ready. You could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/10569220) for an example too.
Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question

Comment: I disagree, I'm suggesting another way to solve what the OP is asking, by using a docker-compose file from another source, and providing links to the docs where it's explained in detail. I don't see the problem in doing so, @SiHa could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't read like that. If using the docker-compose removes the need for manually building with httplib2, that's great. But you've not said that. If the reasons are explained in the links, then copy the relevant parts of the documentation *into the answer*. This is little more than a [link-only-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288055/please-define-link-only-answer) at the moment

Comment: I guess I could just add a comment suggesting the link to a different approach, I tried to provided some context or explanation. @SiHa Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep that in mind for future answers.

Comment: Where would you add the httplib2 library on the official docker-compose file?

Comment: @Erika_Marsha check this [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/10569220), you will see an example on how to do it.