# airflow 2 / docker-compose: how to install Python dependencies for DAGs?

Tags: python, docker-compose, dependencies, airflow

I have installed airflow 2.0.2 using docker-compose as described under https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html.

I have researched quite some time, but I don't find a way to install python dependencies for my DAGs. I know how to do this using a Dockerfile (`COPY requirements.txt /app` / `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`), but there is no Dockerfile involved here.

- How to install python dependencies in airflow 2.0.2 / docker-compose?
- On which of the six containers which are deployed when using the custom docker-compose do I need to install the dependencies?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/10569220), I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have seen this as well, but Apache seems to have changed its documentation, and I cannot find the mentioned content where the link points to. Without this information, I do not understand the reply...

Comment: You were right links were changed, I just updated them.

Comment: glad to heard that! (don't forget to upvote that answer xD)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
image: apache/airflow:x.x.x
```

in your docker compose you want to set this to

```
build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

and then write this to your Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:x.x.x

COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
```

where your requirements.txt contains the python packages. So you're not using the image but instead build it again with also installing the python packages.