# Building airflow in docker compose with pycurl in requirements gets Permission denied: 'curl-config'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow, pycurl

**The problem**

When building a docker image for apache airflow, build fails at *RUN pip install -r requirements.txt* (when installing pycurl package) with:

```
Permission denied: 'curl-config'
```

**What I think the problem is**

I think this problem relates to airflow insisting on packages in requirements.txt being installed by a non-root user (ie 'airflow'). When adding *USER root* to the dockerfile, it errors out with *You are running pip as root. Please use 'airflow' user to run pip!*

Other non-airflow docker containers are installing their packages without seeing this issue

**What I've tried**

- creating a docker group, adding the user and owning the socket - every type of answer listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top)
- removing the requirements.txt step and adding the packages instead to the docker-compose.yaml file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851351/cannot-install-additional-requirements-to-apache-airflow)
- changing the airflow user id to 50000

None of this has resolved the problem - it is always the same error.

**Code I'm using**

The code I'm using can be got from here:

`curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.2/docker-compose.yaml`

I am following [this install documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin)

The requirements are:

```
awscli==1.20.65 
beeline==0.0.9a0 
boto3==1.18.65 
botocore==1.21.65
croniter==1.0.15
elasticsearch==7.13.4
setuptools==58.5.3
Jinja2==2.11.3
krbticket==1.0.6 
pycurl==7.44.1 
PyHive==0.6.4
pyhocon==0.3.58 
requests-kerberos==0.13.0 
requests==2.27.1
python-dotenv==0.20.0
impyla==0.17.0
pandas==1.5.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try

`sudo curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.2/docker-compose.yaml'`

To not get the permission denied, because the command needs to be run by the root user.