# Why extending docker-airflow image, making my scheduler container unhealthy?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am running airflow using the official docker yml file. [official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html)

I extended my image using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.0.2
USER root
RUN apt-get update
USER airflow
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir plotly==4.9
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir svglib==1.1.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir fpdf2
```

Doing that resulted in my scheduler conatiner to go unhealthy

 How can I fix this issue?

[unhealth scheduler container after extending the official image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e0gL.png)

This is the Log I am getting from the container:

```
{
  "Status": "unhealthy",
  "FailingStreak": 7,
  "Log": [
    {
      "Start": "2021-06-16T12:53:53.059066625Z",
      "End": "2021-06-16T12:53:53.843581477Z",
      "ExitCode": 2,
      "Output": "\nairflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: invalid choice: 'jobs' (choose from 'celery', 'cheat-sheet', 'config', 'connections', 'dags', 'db', 'info', 'kerberos', 'kubernetes', 'plugins', 'pools', 'providers', 'roles', 'rotate-fernet-key', 'scheduler', 'sync-perm', 'tasks', 'users', 'variables', 'version', 'webserver'), see help above.\nusage: airflow [-h] GROUP_OR_COMMAND ...\n\npositional arguments:\n  GROUP_OR_COMMAND\n\n    Groups:\n      celery         Celery components\n      config         View configuration\n      connections    Manage connections\n      dags           Manage DAGs\n      db             Database operations\n      kubernetes     Tools to help run the KubernetesExecutor\n      pools          Manage pools\n      providers      Display providers\n      roles          Manage roles\n      tasks          Manage tasks\n      users          Manage users\n      variables      Manage variables\n\n    Commands:\n      cheat-sheet    Display cheat sheet\n      info           Show information about current Airflow and environment\n      kerberos       Start a kerberos ticket renewer\n      plugins        Dump information about loaded plugins\n      rotate-fernet-key\n                     Rotate encrypted connection credentials and variables\n      scheduler      Start a scheduler instance\n      sync-perm      Update permissions for existing roles and DAGs\n      version        Show the version\n      webserver      Start a Airflow webserver instance\n\noptional arguments:\n  -h, --help         show this help message and exit\n"
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read all information in link you provided carefully, there is a phrase: 
*This file uses the latest Airflow image (apache/airflow). If you need install a new Python library or system library, you can customize and extend it.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow: how to get pip packages installed via their docker-compose.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699394/airflow-how-to-get-pip-packages-installed-via-their-docker-compose-yml)

Comment: @Howaboutnope I did go through that and extended my image however, after building the compose file my schedular container is going unhealthy.

Comment: Add more logs form that unhealthy container `docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" <container name> | jq `

Comment: "Output": "\nairflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: invalid choice: 'jobs' (choose from 'celery', 'cheat-sheet', 'config', 'connections', 'dags', 'db', 'info', 'kerberos', 'kubernetes', 'plugins', 'pools', 'providers', 'roles', 'rotate-fernet-key', 'scheduler', 'sync-perm', 'tasks', 'users', 'variables', 'version', 'webserver'), see help above.\nusage: airflow [-h] GROUP_OR_COMMAND ...\n\npositional arguments:\n  GROUP_OR_COMMAND\n\n    Groups:\n      celery         Celery components\n      config

Comment: View configuration\n      connections    Manage connections\n      dags           Manage DAGs\n      db             Database operations\n      kubernetes     Tools to help run the KubernetesExecutor\n      pools          Manage pools\n      providers      Display providers\n      roles          Manage roles\n      tasks          Manage tasks\n      users          Manage users\n      variables      Manage variables\n\n    Commands:\n      cheat-sheet    Display cheat sheet\n      info           Show information about current Airflow and

Comment: environment\n      kerberos       Start a kerberos ticket renewer\n      plugins        Dump information about loaded plugins\n      rotate-fernet-key\n                     Rotate encrypted connection credentials and variables\n      scheduler      Start a scheduler instance\n      sync-perm      Update permissions for existing roles and DAGs\n      version        Show the version\n      webserver      Start a Airflow webserver instance\n\noptional arguments:\n  -h, --help         show this help message and exit\n"
    }

Comment: From other post, there is a suggestion that you might need/want to install build-essential.  If it was me, I would also use pip via `python -m pip`

Comment: @Howaboutnope this is what I am getting

Comment: @JonSG added the log to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my issue.

In my extended image i was using airflow 2.0.2 and which was not compatible. Upgrading to airflow 2.1.0 solved my problem.

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         build-essential libopenmpi-dev \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update
USER airflow
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir plotly==4.9
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir svglib==1.1.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir fpdf2
```