# Can't import created package from plugins folder

Tags: python, pip, airflow, python-module

I am running apache Airflow using docker-compose and Dockerfile, and I have the following airflow folder structure:

```
dags
    example_dag
         dag_1.py
pf_utils
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    db.py --> get_primary_keys function
plugins
    _init_.py
    snowflake_operator.py --> from pf_utils.db import get_primary_keys
```

I have created a package from the folder utils, in order to be able to import its functions in the dags and plugin codes, following the instructions in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#creating-a-package-in-python

However, the import in the `snowflake_operator` file fails due to not existing module. How could I make it work in the snowflake operator file?

If I enter the container(s) with `docker exec -it airflow_scheduler_1 bash`, I can see that the package `pf_utils` is correctly installed for two reasons:

- Running `pip show pf_utils` shows me:

  ```
   Name: pf-utils
   Version: 0.0.0
   Summary: UNKNOWN
   Home-page: UNKNOWN
   Author: None
   Author-email: None
   License: UNKNOWN
   Location: /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
   Requires: 
   Required-by:
  ```
- Within the home (`/opt/airflow`), running `import pf_utils` in a python3 console gives no error.

However, if I move from `/opt/airflow` to `/opt/airflow/plugins` and I launch `python3` there, the import will raise an error of not existing module. In the working directory `/opt/airflow/plugins` I have tried also with:

```
from .pf_utils.db import get_primary_keys
import .pf_utils
import ..pf_utils
from ..pf_utils import db
from airflow.pf_utils import db
```

None of the above work

Even adding the lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/airflow/pf_utils')
```

To the beginning of the snowflake_operator.py file doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: How are you installing `pf_utils` package? Try using [_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#environment-variables-supported-by-docker-compose) in the docker compose file or adding it to your custom image like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/10569220).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Airflow 2, importing operators/sensors etc from Plugins is no longer supported

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html#plugins

> Changed in version 2.0: Importing operators, sensors, hooks added in
> plugins via airflow.{operators,sensors,hooks}.<plugin_name> is no
> longer supported, and these extensions should just be imported as
> regular python modules. For more information, see: Modules Management
> and Creating a custom Operator

Plugins used to be used for that in 1.10 but even there it was not needed (and harmful sometimes). This is not there any more - plugins are there to add macros and customise views of UI or add "whole Airlfow installation behavioural changes" (See the plugins link above for examples when plugins should be used).

In Airflow 2 (and it also works in Airflow 1.10) new operators/sensors/hooks should be added as regular python packages only:

1. Either in dags folder or any other folder that you add in PYTHONPATH (usually if you want to iterate and change those operators together with the dags). Those operators etc. can be excluded from being parsed by scheduler by  proper exclusion in .airflowignore: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html?highlight=airflowignore#loading-dags
2. As regular python packages installed in your environment (usually when you test and release your operators independently from changing the DAGS).
3. As Provider packages - if you want to group logically a number of those to interface with particular service and you want to add custom Connections with custom UI components, add Operator's extra links - this will allow you to register some of those Hooks/Operators as providing new connections and Extra links.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jarek. I know this was the case and indeed I have been using custom hooks/operators as regular packages. I used "plugins" meaning a custom operator that is placed under the plugins directory, which is by default added to python path, and not a custom operator added using the plugins mechanism. Sorry for the missexplanation

Comment: Just move it to "dags" - this is where it conceptually belongs. And I think if you move it to plugins, what will work is adding "/opt/airlfow/plugins" to PYTHONPATH BTW (I think you've added "/opt/airflow/pf_utils" :).