# Installing dependencies on Docker Containers - Airflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm using a Docker Container to run some python scripts. I need to install `pymssql` in the container. I've runned the CLI and used `pip install pymssql` to install this package. Although, when I refresh my airflow webpage, it keeps showing me an error that `pymssql` is not installed:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/utils/havanutils/__init__.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/utils/havanutils/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pymssql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymssql'
```

I'm running CLI in Docker Desktop like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be1TN.png).

Am I running the correct CLI? Or this packages should be installed through another CLI?

Comment: Try checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/10569220) for an example and references on how to customize the Airflow image docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the `pymssql` installation during docker build time. Otherwise every-time you stop the container you have to reinstall `pymssql`.

You should add following line in your `Dockerfile` :

`RUN pip install pymssql` ; if there is only one installation or

`RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` and add your installations in a `requirements.txt` file like
`pymssql==2.2.2`

Comment: Can i add these lines inside my `docker-compose.yaml` file?

Comment: @OdiumPura No, this file is Dockerfile which is different from docker-compose.yml. Dockerfile is used to create a docker container with specification. [Here is difference between both](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/what-is-the-difference-between-dockerfile-and-docker-compose-yml-files/)

Answer (score 0):

Docker images are effectively immutable at runtime.

You should create your image image, push it to a Docker Registry, then make your Airflow tasks use that

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you provide me a link or a tutorial to do that?