# Error with botocore in apache airflow-windows

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow, botocore

I have set the variables and connections in apache airflow webUI, so when i try to import the s3 hook from aiflow hooks,so i use to get the keys in the s3 bucket, but it fails, and i get the following error:

```
[2021-08-24 21:59:11,720] {{dagbag.py:246}} ERROR - Failed to import: 
/usr/local/airflow/dags/lesson4.py
webserver_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 
243, in process_file
webserver_1  |     m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
webserver_1  |     module = _load(spec)
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
webserver_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/lesson4.py", line 9, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3hook
webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py", line 
19, in <module>
webserver_1  |     from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
webserver_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore'


import datetime
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
#import airflow.hooks.S3_hook as S3Hook
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook


def list_keys():
    hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws_credentials')
    bucket = Variable.get('s3_bucket')
    prefix = Variable.get('s3_prefix')
    logging.info(f"Listing Keys from {bucket}/{prefix}")
    keys = hook.list_keys(bucket, prefix=prefix)
    for key in keys:
        logging.info(f"- s3://{bucket}/{key}")


dag = DAG(
        'lesson1.exercise4',
        start_date=datetime.datetime.now())

list_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="list_keys",
    python_callable=list_keys,
    dag=dag
```

)

Can anyone show me how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have `botocore` installed which is a PIP requiriment of the [Amazon provider package](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/index.html).

You can install the provider package on top of your Airflow 2.1+ using pip:

`pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon`

Once installed, if you run `airflow info` from the CLI, you should see it listed under *Providers info*  section.

```
...
Providers info
apache-airflow-providers-amazon          | 2.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-celery          | 2.0.0
apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes | 2.0.0
...
```

If you are running Airflow using Docker Compose, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701128/10569220) may help you on how to install pip packages in the containers.

Comment: It didn't work, can you help me in doing this via the docker? I checked the link, but still didn't know how to do this

Comment: @joe8ones sure, follow this tutorial about [how to install Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) using the official docker-compose definition. Once everything is running you won't need to install any extra package since [amazon provider package](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2c6c7fdb2308de98e142618836bdf414df9768c8/Dockerfile#L37) is installed by default in the Airflow docker image.